# using switch or multiple ternarys

Tags: php, standards

so I'm wondering is their any reason to use multiple ternary vs a switch statement. I'm thinking that with the speed of development in mind and all the time spent on boarding new programmers at varing levels of experience. If their is no or very little performance increase by using confusing code that is shorter but harder to understand is it really a benifit if it slows down new development. (I'm using a very simple example but i figure most have encountered a section of code that made us scratch our head and pause for a moment.

Extremly simple example

```
switch ($cartItem->cart_item_type) {
    case 'RA':
        $wireTransferData['pending-RA'] = true;
        break;

    case 'FT':
        $wireTransferData['pending-FT'] = true;
        break;

    default:// MF
        $wireTransferData['pending-MF'] = true;
        break;
}
```

VS

```
$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] =  ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);
$wireTransferData['pending-FT'] =  ('FT' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);
$wireTransferData['pending-MF'] =  ('MF' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);
```

I feel that even though the switch takes more lines it is clearer and can be understood quicker then the ternary option. (again this is a very basic example). Just wondering about what others are thinking on this topic.

Comment: As long as you only want a true/false value from a ternary, you can get rid of the true/false statements inside the result. For example: `$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] =  ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);` is equivalent to
`$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] =  ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items);`. This could help you make the visual decision on performance.

Comment: Personally, in this situation I believe the ternary operators are more elegant and make more sense to have.

Comment: The 2 versions are not equivalent, at least not in the code above.  With the switch there is the possibility that the other 2 keys, the not values, are left undefined.  And the switch will handle unknown values of `$pendingOrder->items` the ternary wont.  In the case of the switch and an unknown value this `$wireTransferData['pending-MF']` is true, with the ternary it's false.... Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 versions are not equivalent, at least not in the code provided.

With the switch there is the possibility that the other 2 keys, the not values, are left undefined. Even when a known value of `$pendingOrder->items` is used. In the Ternary they all default to false.

The switch will handle unknown values of `$pendingOrder->items` the ternary wont. In the case of the switch and an unknown value this `$wireTransferData['pending-MF']` is `true`, with the ternary it's `false`....

```
$cartItem->cart_item_type = 'foo';

switch ($cartItem->cart_item_type) {
    case 'RA':
        $wireTransferData['pending-RA'] = true;
        break;

    case 'FT':
        $wireTransferData['pending-FT'] = true;
        break;

    default:// MF
        $wireTransferData['pending-MF'] = true;
        break;
}

// - $wireTransferData['pending-MF'] = true;
// - $wireTransferData['pending-RA'] is undefined;
// - $wireTransferData['pending-FT'] is undefined;
```

---

```
$cartItem->cart_item_type = 'foo';

$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] =  ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);
$wireTransferData['pending-FT'] =  ('FT' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);
$wireTransferData['pending-MF'] =  ('MF' == $pendingOrder->items ? true : false);

// - $wireTransferData['pending-MF'] = false;
// - $wireTransferData['pending-RA'] = false;
// - $wireTransferData['pending-FT'] = false;
```

Just some thoughts. These are subtle differences but they can result in edge case bugs in application code.

In my opinion they are used for different things.  Or they are used to define the data in a different way if that makes sense.  Depending on your use case what I mentioned above may be important, and one or the other may be the better choice simply by how the data is defined.

On the other hand that might not matter at all and you can use some other criteria to make that choice.  Functionality is first IMO.

Personally I would use the ternary (or see below) in this case. The reason is that the keys of `$wireTransferData` are different. Which with the switch leaving these undefined could cause more problems downstream and require more code to handle.  But that assessment is based on very little context.

**UPDATE**

I do agree with the other answers that this:

```
$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] =  ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items);
```

Is better then the Ternary when you just want a boolean.  Which should be "kinda" obvious, but I thought I would mention it just in case as I refereed to it collectively as "Ternary" above...  This method (lets call it "conditional" ) is basically equivalent to the Ternary as far as functionality goes.

**One last thing**

Another way is to simply do this:

```
 $wireTransferData['pending-'.$cartItem->cart_item_type] = true;
```

Or

```
$types = ['pending-MF','pending-RA','pending-FT']; //default is first item

//- function foo($cartItem, $types=['pending-MF','pending-RA','pending-FT']){...}

$wireTransferData = array_fill_keys($types,false); //default all to false
if(in_array('pending-'.$cartItem->cart_item_type, $types)){
    $wireTransferData['pending-'.$cartItem->cart_item_type] = true;
}else{
    $wireTransferData[$types[0]] = true; //pending-MF => true
}
```

Which does everything that the Switch and ternary do (default false, set default value, check for acceptable types etc..) and is dynamic based on a `$types` array.  Which is probably the best way, but I figure this is an "academic" question.

Cheers

Comment: I agree, these are definitely not equivalent.

Comment: btw, I didn't mean to ignore your comment to me on a different question last week. I was just on my way out the door and never got a chance to get back to it over the weekend.

Comment: - It's all good!

Comment: @Don'tPanic - that had to do with template lexing if you want some code examples you can check these out on [Github](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers)

Answer (score 1):

The ternary adds unnecessary complexity. The comparison expression already evaluates to a boolean.

```
$wireTransferData['pending-RA'] = ('RA' == $pendingOrder->items);
$wireTransferData['pending-FT'] = ('FT' == $pendingOrder->items);
$wireTransferData['pending-MF'] = ('MF' == $pendingOrder->items);
```

The parentheses aren't necessary either, but I think they do make it more obvious what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case multiple ternary operators would make better sense here, not just for readability but to prevent errors later on. For what it's worth I think both of these examples are quite readable.

The reason I'm deciding on multiple ternary operators is to define each array index as true or false. I can't tell if that is absolutely needed from this example but the switch would only define the index if it's true. This would require additional checks later on to make sure the index exists before reading the value.

Depending on the actual application, I would change how this is written so that I'm setting the index of "pending" to "RA", "FT", "MF", or ""/false/null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another less verbose solution supposing the values in `cart_item_type` do not resemble `$wireTransferData` keys :

```
$types = [
    'RA' => 'pending-RA',
    'FT' => 'pending-FT',
    'MF' => 'pending-MF'
];

$wireTransferData[$types[$cartItem->cart_item_type]] = true; //readable?
```